# Jquery Ajax form no success message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html form that works on my local machine without a problem.
When I upload it it works as well but does not show the success message.
This is the script I am using:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#_form_1033").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
            $("#myformdiv").replaceWith("<p>Thanks!</p>");           
            }            
        });
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Any advice?
Link to live example - http://ch2.co.il/form/smallsubscribe2015.html
Could it be this error - if so how can I fix it?
XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ch2.co.il' is therefore not allowed access.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are making a cross-domain AJAX request, which prevented by browser security - see the **[Same Origin Policy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)**

The request is expecting you to be making a request to a CORS enabled domain, hence why it is complaining about the non-existant header.

You either need to change your request to `jsonp` type, or use a server-side proxy to get the data.

So better add `crossDomain:true` to your ajax function as below

```
$("#_form_1033").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            crossDomain:true,
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
            $("#myformdiv").replaceWith("<p>Thanks!</p>");           
            }            
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Reply. This is what fixed it:

```
dataType: "json",
```